# the curious case of backslashes in uploaded file pathnames on xampp + cake

Tags: cakephp, xampp

XAMPP + Cake installation on Windows 7 causes the curious problem of introducing backslashes in pathnames of uploaded files.

Comment: Professor Plum, in the library, with the Candlestick! Did I win??

Comment: Can you give an example of the problematic pathname? I would normally very much expect a Windows filepath to contain backslashes...

Comment: Any language translations going on that might have weird characters that need to be escaped?  Is it only adding the backslashes next to a comma, for example?  Or is it properly escaping illegal windows filenames so they can be stored in the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a case of needing to define the directory separator? See this from webroot/index.php:

```
/**
 * Use the DS to separate the directories in other defines
 */
    if (!defined('DS')) {
        define('DS', '/');//DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

}
```

/**